# Nginx redirecting to 443

Tags: nginx, webserver

I have several apps running on a server. Iv configured an app with the port 8892 but nginx keep redirecting to 443. Had anyone a similar error ever. Its so strange all other apps are working properly.

Here is my config file:

```
    server {
             listen 8892 ssl default_server;
             listen [::]:8892 ssl default_server;

    #return 301 https://$host$request_uri$is_args$args;
 root /var/www/html;


            index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

            server_name server.seyo-iv.space;

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6080;

         Forward the Host header, which is used to route requests for
         static content published from Sandstorm apps.
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        # Forward WebSocket.
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      }

      receive large uploads.
      client_max_body_size 1024m;

        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.seyo-iv.space/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.seyo-iv.space/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:1m; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_session_timeout 1440m; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256 EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA"; # managed by Certbot


    }
```

Comment: Have you cleared the browser cache since commenting out the `return 301` and restarting Nginx?

Comment: no still not working. But i got it working that way. The new app now listen to 443 and i did commentout `listen 443 ssl` in the config files of my apps. Now everything is working properly.